# Qt: How to integrate / embed Qt application in other framework like OpenGL for example?

Tags: qt, integration

Hello all
I'm using Qt for desktop application but never needed to take portion of Qt in my case QWebkit and some widgets and use
Them from other application like opengl application . 
For example simple flow .
A button in the OpenGL application  opens Qt Widget ,then the user fill some details and return the focus back to the OpenGL application 
How can it be done ?

Comment: how do i accept all the questions i forgot to accept ?